# get average interarrival time for service requests by timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

I have partly the following MySQL schema

```
ServiceRequests
----------
id int  
RequestDateTime datetime
```

This is what a typical collection of records might look like.

```
1 | 2009-10-11 14:34:22
2 | 2009-10-11 14:34:56
3 | 2009-10-11 14:35:01
```

In this case the average request time is (34+5)/2 = 19.5 seconds, being

```
14:34:22 ---> (34 seconds) ----> 14:34:56 ------> (5 seconds) -----> 14:35:01
```

Basically I need to work out the difference in time between consecutive records, sum that up and divide by the number of records.

The closest thing I can think of is to convert the timestamp to epoch time and start there. I can add a field to the table to precalculate the epoch time if necessary.

How do I determine 19.5 using a sql statement(s)?

Comment: A beautiful start is to show the query you've tried so far

Comment: Do consecutive records in time order always have consecutive IDs?

Comment: The id field is autoincremented but sometimes this table is partially cleared so the records are not always n+1. ie typically they look like 1,2,4,7,8,9,367,368. I have python code for this but I'd like it done in sql so I don't have anything to show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need to know the time difference of each record to get the average.  You have x data points ranging from some point t0 to t1. *Notice that the `the last time` - `first time` is also 39 sec.* `(max-min)/(count-1)` should work for you

```
select max(RequestDateTime)-min(RequestDateTime) / (count(id)-1) from ServiceRequests;
```

**Note:** This will not work if the table is empty, due to a divide by zero.

**Note2:** Different databases handle subtraction of dates differently so you may need to turn that difference into seconds.

*Hint:* maybe using TIMEDIFF(expr1,expr2) and/or TIME_TO_SEC(expr3)

Comment: Thank you! I guess I was over-engineering somewhere, for now my requirement really is as simple as your answer suggests.